# excel vba: line break in code

Tags: vba, excel

I have a rather lengthy formula in excel vba that I'm being forced to break into multiple lines.  I've tried inserting a " _" but I'm getting the following error:

"Compile error:  Expected: end of statement"

I've looked over this code several times and cant seem to find what is driving this error.  If someone could look over the code below and help me figure this out I'd greatly appreciate it.  Thanks in advance.

```
        If InStr(1, lineitem.Value, "Excess MO") > 0 And InStr(1, lineitem.Value, "AOS") > 0 Then
        lineitem.Offset(0, 16).Formula = "=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(INDIRECT(""'""&R2C3&"" Claims'!B:B""),R[0]C[-19],INDIRECT(""'""&R2C3&"" Claims'!C:C""),R[0]C[-17],INDIRECT(""'""&R2C3&"" Claims'!E:E""),CHOOSE({1;2},R[0]C[-15],R[0]C[-14]),INDIRECT(""'""&R2C3&"" Claims'!P:P""),"">""&R5C3,INDIRECT(""'""&R2C3&"" Claims'!H:H""),""<>""&""NS""))- _
        SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(INDIRECT(""'""&R2C3&"" Claims'!B:B""),R[0]C[-19],INDIRECT(""'""&R2C3&"" Claims'!C:C""),R[0]C[-17],INDIRECT(""'""&R2C3&"" Claims'!E:E""),CHOOSE({1;2},R[0]C[-15],R[0]C[-14]),INDIRECT(""'""&R2C3&"" Claims'!P:P""),"">""&R5C3,INDIRECT(""'""&R2C3&"" Claims'!H:H""),""<>""&""NS"",INDIRECT(""'""&R2C3&"" Claims'!G:G""),R2C5:R2C27))- _
        SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(INDIRECT(""'""&R2C3&"" Claims'!B:B""),R[0]C[-19],INDIRECT(""'""&R2C3&"" Claims'!C:C""),R[0]C[-17],INDIRECT(""'""&R2C3&"" Claims'!E:E""),CHOOSE({1;2},R[0]C[-15],R[0]C[-14]),INDIRECT(""'""&R2C3&"" Claims'!P:P""),"">""&R5C3,INDIRECT(""'""&R2C3&"" Claims'!H:H""),""<>""&""NS"",INDIRECT(""'""&R2C3&"" Claims'!G:G""),R5C5:R5C54))"
        lineitem.Offset(0, 16).Value = lineitem.Offset(0, 16).Value
        lineitem.Offset(0, 17).Formula = "=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(INDIRECT(""'""&R3C3&"" Claims'!B:B""),R[0]C[-20],INDIRECT(""'""&R3C3&"" Claims'!C:C""),R[0]C[-18],INDIRECT(""'""&R3C3&"" Claims'!E:E""),CHOOSE({1;2},R[0]C[-16],R[0]C[-15]),INDIRECT(""'""&R3C3&"" Claims'!P:P""),"">""&R5C3,INDIRECT(""'""&R3C3&"" Claims'!H:H""),""<>""&""NS""))- _
        SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(INDIRECT(""'""&R3C3&"" Claims'!B:B""),R[0]C[-20],INDIRECT(""'""&R3C3&"" Claims'!C:C""),R[0]C[-18],INDIRECT(""'""&R3C3&"" Claims'!E:E""),CHOOSE({1;2},R[0]C[-16],R[0]C[-15]),INDIRECT(""'""&R3C3&"" Claims'!P:P""),"">""&R5C3,INDIRECT(""'""&R3C3&"" Claims'!H:H""),""<>""&""NS"",INDIRECT(""'""&R3C3&"" Claims'!G:G""),R2C5:R2C27))- _
        SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(INDIRECT(""'""&R3C3&"" Claims'!B:B""),R[0]C[-20],INDIRECT(""'""&R3C3&"" Claims'!C:C""),R[0]C[-18],INDIRECT(""'""&R3C3&"" Claims'!E:E""),CHOOSE({1;2},R[0]C[-16],R[0]C[-15]),INDIRECT(""'""&R3C3&"" Claims'!P:P""),"">""&R5C3,INDIRECT(""'""&R2C3&"" Claims'!H:H""),""<>""&""NS"",INDIRECT(""'""&R3C3&"" Claims'!G:G""),R5C5:R5C54))"
        lineitem.Offset(0, 17).Value = lineitem.Offset(0, 17).Value
        End If
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Line breaks don't work like that.

You need something like:

```
   fset(0, 16).Formula = "THISIS() + " & _
                         "REALLYLONG()"
```

Comment: is it because I'm using spreadsheet formulas in vba?  I don't normally use them

Comment: You are *inside* a string and except for `"` it will ignore any syntax. This way you need to end the string to make the `_` useable.

Comment: @GrahamChandler Remember to check the answer as correct when you get the right answer